# sa_handler function; can't access class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, thread-synchronization

I am trying to build a multi threaded program that will create four instances of a `Child` and "run" a set of "expensive" `Job`s. The parent will send a signal indicating when they shall all start. Now, each child thread must then catch that signal. It has inside of it a `sig_handler`. It's a private class inside of `Child`. 
So far I have it defined as:

```
private:
class sig_handler {
    typedef struct sigaction sigAct;
    Shared* sh;
    //============
    void whatSig();
public:
    sig_handler( Shared* s );
    sigAct action;
    sigset_t signalset;              // Just want siguser and sigquit
    static void catchSig( int sig ); // interacts with the shared resource
                                     // it starts up the threads
};
```

First off, is it even ok to have a class as a signal handler? If it is ok (which would certainly make the readibility better), how would we implement it?

I am trying to catch `SIGUSR1` so that I can change a flag in `Shared` memory. Each thread has access to `Shared` memory through a pointer to this object, i.e. `Shared* share`. This is done using a class to act as a kind of shared base.

Now here is what I really need answered. I begin setting up my `sigset_t signalSet`:

```
Child::sig_handler::sig_handler( Shared* s ) {
    sh = s;

    sigemptyset(&signalset);
    sigaddset(&signalset, SIGUSR1);     // Add these to the now empty set
    sigaddset(&signalset, SIGQUIT);

    action.sa_handler = catchSig;       // 1
    action.sa_mask = signalset;
    action.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);  // attach the class member action
}
```

Really pay attention to line 1. This is a critical spot. This I think has to be a static or global function. This is where an error can be happening. When I make my class method `catchSig(int sig)` non static, line 1 complains `Reference to a non-static function call must be called`. I have it defined as such when this happens: `void catchSig( int sig );`
When I define it as `static void catchSig( int sig );`, the compiler complains on line 2.

```
void Child::sig_handler::catchSig(int sig) {
    sh->startflag;    // 2
}
```

It says, `Invalid use of 'sh' in static member function`. I need to be able to have access to this variable. How can I fix it so that I can have my `sig_handler` class, and share through `catchSig()`?

### Update:

I implemented StoryTeller's suggestion of using a pointer to `this`. While it worked to stop the complaining of the compiler, I still have a buildtime error. I altered the definition of `sig_handler` to now be this:

```
private:
class sig_handler {
    typedef struct sigaction sigAct;
    Shared* sh;
    static sig_handler* self;
    //============
    void whatSig();
public:
    sig_handler( Shared* s );
    sigAct action;
    sigset_t signalset;
    static void catchSig( int sig ); // interacts with the shared resource
                                     // it starts up the threads
};
```

Take note of the new `static` pointer to itself. This was done so that I can have access to the variable `sh`, the shared resource that I need. Which I use as such:

```
void Child::sig_handler::catchSig(int sig) {
    self->sh->setStartFlag(true);    // this was were it used to complain
}
```

The `sig_handler` is created in the `Child` constructor (`sigHand = new sig_handler(share)`). I get a build time error stated below. What is happening? How can this be fixed?

```
"Child::sig_handler::self", referenced from:
 Child::sig_handler::sig_handler(Shared*) in Child.o
 Child::sig_handler::catchSig(int) in Child.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

### Update 2:

Essentially, it's not possible to make a `sig_handler` class unfortunately.

Comment: You can't just "fix" it. The signal callbacks don't accept user data intentionally. The only recourse is some static data that the signal handler may access.

Comment: @StoryTeller so "user data" of sh can't be used here? And that is because it is non-static, correct?

Comment: The data can't be used because the handler has no way to reach it. The error says as much, static member functions don't have access to `this`.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes a lot of sense why sh can't be reached by catchSig(). How, then, can catchSig() still use sh? Their is a variable inside of there, startFlag, that signals to all of the other threads when to start. This is so I can synchronize their start execution of their Jobs.

Comment: Well, static data it would have to be. I don't know your exact setup, but it may be as simple as a static pointer that you set to `this`. Or perhaps a `map` of pointers if you want different signals to have different handler object. That's why I said it's not "fixable". You need a redesign of some sort.

Comment: Hmm. A `map` seems a little too complicated for this issue. The static pointer to `this` that you mention is certainly interesting. I've also never heard of such a thing. Would you mind posting a more in-depth answer? Also, would you like to see the encapsulating class `Child`? Or even `Shared`?

Comment: The static pointer? It's just `private: static sig_handler* handler;` You'll need to manage the lifetime properly of course. I don't really feel this is all particularly answer worthy though :)